What's the difference between a Mac build built on Windows vs Mac?
As many of you know, you generally can not build a Mac version of your Unity game on Windows, or at least, you have to add the executable bit using the chmod command on Linux or Mac.
Yet, even with the executable bit set, the identical builds built on Mac and Windows still have one key difference. The Mac version does not require you to accept the security risks with opening the application, not even if you try it on a second Mac.
How does MacOS know whether a Unity App was built on Mac/Windows? Where in the app files is it saved? Is it saved in the build itself at all?
Together with some acquaintances, we tried all sorts of things to figure out the answer to this question.
Up until now, we compared file flags on a file to file basis between builds, which did not get us an answer.
Comparing file contents of the whole build, results in a small list of files which are different from the build built on Mac vs the one built on Windows.
One of those files is at game.app/Contents/MacOS/_CodeSignature/CodeResources, it seems to contain a dictionary of the files in the build and a corresponding key/hash. Every such hash that's different between both builds, belongs to a file that was flagged as different between both builds too, but none of the files seem to have some kind of signature by Apple, by which the builds can be differentiated.

For MacOS/iOS/iPadOS the MachO file format is used. This format can contain (similar to Windows PE format) the signature inside the executable or library file itself.
The reason why only builds done in MacOS are signed is that the necessary signing tools are not provided by Apple for other OS than MacOS: codesign.
For Linux I think there are some Open Source tools available that claim to also to do MachO code signing but I don't know how good they are. And in the end you always need a code signing cert+key from Apple.
If you want to look ate the MachO structure there are a lot of command-line tools like otool available or for UI for example XMachOViewer.

Thank you for this answer. In the meantime, I have figured something else out: builds for Mac built on a Mac do in fact get the warning for malicious software, if you download it from the internet. Any build, built on either Windows or Mac, do not show the warning, if transferred via USB-Stick. Can I therefore conclude my question was redundant and can be closed?
